# Setting Up OpenGL in Qt for QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I have some old OpenGL code that I created with GLEW. I am trying to port this code into Qt 5.4, the old code contains `Mesh`, `Shader`, and `Texture` classes.

What I have so far in Qt, is the default main window and a `Visualizer` class which inherits from `QOpenGLWidget` and `QOpenGLFunctions`. I am able to display the widget as a black box by setting `MainWindow` as the parent of `Visualizer`.

In order to compile the old OpenGL code which uses functions like `glGenVertexArrays();` I made the classes inherit from `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core`. I also call `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` where necessary such as inside `initializeGL()` of the `Visualizer` class and in the constructors of `Mesh`, `Shader`, and `Texture`.

It all compiles well. But when I run the program it crashes when the function `glGenVertexArrays();` is called when trying to create a `Mesh` object.

I am guessing there was a memory violation of some sort. Do I have to setup an OpenGL context in Qt manually for the `QOpenGLWidget`?

How can I setup OpenGL 3.3 properly with Qt so I can use an `QOpenGLWidget` to render OpenGL content and use all of those OpenGL functions such as `glGenVertexArrays()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an interesting solution. Perhaps it was obvious but I didn't see it at first. I basically created a single static variable of type `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core` inside a dummy class, `GL`, and used that through out the entire code whenever an OpenGL function was needed.

For example

```
class GL{
  public:
    static QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core funcs;
}

...

class Visualizer : public QOpenGLWidget{

   ...

   void initializeGL(){
      GL::funcs.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
   }
   ...
}

...

// Example usage
GL::funcs.glGenVertexArrays(1, &id);
GL::funcs.glClearColor(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
```